# gap_init:2 with Cordova and Crosswalk

Tags: cordova, cordova-3, crosswalk-runtime

I compiled an app using Cordova 3.6.3 and Crosswalk. When I start it I always get a prompt with `gap_init:2` as default text, OK and Cancel buttons.

Am I doing something wrong? Am I the only one seeing that error?

The `gap_init:2` prompt comes from the `Cordova.js` file:

```
androidExec.init = function() {
    bridgeSecret = +prompt('', 'gap_init:' + nativeToJsBridgeMode);
    channel.onNativeReady.fire();
};
```

When I compile that app using only Cordova, then I never see that prompt.

Comment: try including some code, as this is written it could be anything?

Comment: @DawsonLoudon: indeed, I added more info about the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I recompiled my app with a newer version of CrossWalk and the prompt disappeared. I'm not sure what was causing it.

I also noticed a few other people talking about that prompt when using things like Cocoon/Ludei/webview-plus.

Comment: What version did you end up using? I am using version 18.48.477.13 (the current version, I think), and I get this prompt and two more before the content loads.

Comment: @Bryan: I'm not sure what I was using then. Right now I'm on Cordova iOS 3.9.1 and Android 4.1.1, using ordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview 1.7.0.

Comment: Ah, I have been using the CrossWalk library, not the cordova plugin. Maybe I will try the plugin instead, thank you.

Comment: @user276648 How did you solve the error? I too am getting it. Using the latest Crosswalk library too did not help me. Can you please help me?

Comment: @krishnanspace Sorry, but as mentioned I don't know exactly what was causing the error. At that time simply uses a newer version of CrossWalk did the trick. Also I haven't used CrossWalk for several years as I dropped support for older systems.

Comment: @user276648 Oh.. Thanks for the reply though